# PowerShell to compare arrays of objects with different property names

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am using **PnPPowershell** to import some CSV files into SharePoint lists and am having trouble with the person columns. I want to compare the emails in several CSV columns to a list of known site users and then use some other techniques with the "unknowns." But first I have to identify the unknowns.

I can use `Get-PnPUser` to get all the site (collection) confirmed users and it is an array of object something like this. Currently there are about 720 users in our site.

```
  [PSCustomObject]@{Email=first.mi.last@example.org,
                    Id=9,
                    Title=Rothrock}
```

And then I have the array of object being read from the CSV file. There are about 11,000 of these records and they have many more properties than I've shown here.

```
  [PSCustomObject]@{OwnerEmail=SomePersonOrOther@example.com,
                    ContactEmail=SomebodyElse@example.com,
                    Title=Something or other,
                    ReviewDate=7/25/2022,
                    ...}
```

I need to compare all of the "email" properties/columns from the CSV to the known users and find the "unknown" people.

I found this [page about performing set operations](https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/perform-set-operations-union-intersection-minus-complement-using-powershell/). It uses `Compare-Object` and I read [the MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.2), which has a `-Property` switch for which object property should be compared. For example if I want to compare the email properties of the objects.

```
$result = Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $users $inputCSV -Property email
```

This is working well for me when my object both have a property with the same names. But I want to compare the email property from users with several differently named properties in the CSV. For example compare the **User.Email** to **InputCSV.OwnerEmail** and also to **InputCSV.ContactEmail** and so on.

Is there a way to quickly compare objects with different property names?

Comment: So do you need to compare both OwnerEmail and ContactEmail at the same time or just find out if any of the two values exist in the user array?

Comment: I eventually need to find all the emails that are unknown to the site regardless of which csv column they're in. Doesn't have to be at the same time, but I need to find them all. And the goal for this is to separate out the csv rows that would fail when trying to Add-PnPListItem

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen your code this might be what you are looking for.

```
#Array with users to check against
$users = @("userOne@domain.com","userTwo@domain.com")
#$users = Get-PnPUser

#Array with the rows from the CSV that were found in the 'users' array
$found = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
#Array with the rows from the CSV that were NOT found in the 'users' array
$unknown = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

#Import the CSV normally
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "csvPath\fileName.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8

#Loop through each row in the CSV
ForEach($row in $csv) {
    #check if the array 'users' contain either the current CSV row property 'OwnerEmail or 'ContactEmail'
    If(($users -contains $row.OwnerEmail) -or ($users -contains $row.ContactEmail)) {
        $found.Add($row) | Out-Null
    }
    Else {
        $unknown.Add($row) | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Compare-Object` it will take two passes:

```
$result1 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $users.Email -DifferenceObject  $inputCS.OwnerEmail 

$result1 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $users.Email -DifferenceObject  $inputCS.ContactEmail
```